Local .gradle deamon logs visible in Android Studio search results
As the title says i have a issue which started after updating AGP to 8.6.
The ~/.gradle/deamon/*/*.log files are visible in my Android Studio search results. (So not the projects .gradle but my own local .gradle)

I can ofcourse mark the directory as Excluded and that works for a while until i reboot my PC or restart Android Studio.
What could be the cause of this? I haven't read any reports from other people yet.
